# Why/how would a NAS use Thunderbolt support?

Tags: networking, nas, thunderbolt

Browsing NAS drives, I came across [this one](https://www.qnap.com/en-uk/product/tvs-472xt) from QNAP which...

> features both 10GBASE-T and Thunderbolt™ 3 high-bandwidth connectivity for tackling heavy workloads and smoothly transferring, displaying and editing 4K videos in real-time

I thought Thunderbolt was used to connect peripherals and had only short range. So is the idea someone puts this drive on their desk and just uses it like an external drive? Struggling to see the use-case over Ethernet, can anyone clue me up?

Comment: How many laptops have 10Gbit Ethernet, in comparison to those which have Thunderbolt?

Comment: @user1686 that's why you buy an external drive. Not a NAS... what does the N stand for :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can only get Thunderbolt 3 to travel half a metre at full 40gbps speeds, that's how it would have to be done.
Ref: https://blog.startech.com/post/thunderbolt-3-the-basics/

If you want to drop to 10GBase-T then you're down to [of course] 10gbps, but up to 100m.
Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Gigabit_Ethernet

Most user Ethernet these days is 1/10 that speed, at 1gbps.

<sup>Not sure what they're doing with the TB3 on that QNAS, but it's not running at the full 40gbps anyway, only 10.</sup>

Comment: Maybe we should view it as like an external RAID setup for your local PC rather than a NAS?

Comment: A RAID is a 'storage' method, NAS is a 'connectivity method' on top of a storage method. They connect over SMB, unlike a directly-attached RAID, which runs as a mounted filesystem on the computer.

Comment: If one is to be pedantic - 2.5 gbps is turning into the new 'cheap' standard. Also modern 'Nases' and Sans are literally PCs running file sharing software on top, well probably always have been

Answer (score 0):

Most of these nas type machines have 'proper' X86 or Arm CPUs - running linux or some custom OSes and able to run additional software, even the single drive ones.

Having thunderbolt support's likely a minimal additional cost if supported in the chipset. Many of these machines also have PCIe expansion options for the same reason.

Its a potentially useful feature that can be added on at 'minimal' additional cost

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbolt is typically used for 2 things:
As already mentioned by Tetsujin in another answer to provide a VERY fast alternative to 10 Gb/s LAN for a heavy duty workstation or server that needs to shuffle huge amounts of data back and forth to the NAS and do it fast.
(E.g a video-editing workstation.)
This can also be used to setup a fast point-2-point link between 2 of these NAS boxes so one can act as backup of the other.

The second is as a peripheral interface: To add a an aditional disk-pack to the NAS to extend disk-capacity.
Traditionally NAS devices would use eSATA or SAS for this (or Infiniband/CX4 on the really expensive stuff), but Thunderbolt is for a short point2point conenction about as fast as Infiniband or CX4 and way cheaper. (Newer Intel chipsets have Thunderbolt integrated so you get it more or less for free if the NAS uses an Intel CPU.)